# Normal approximation of Poisson using asymptotics on mass function

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I have an excercise in probability and I need your help:

> Let $X \sim Poi(\lambda )$. Use asymptotics on the mass function directly to prove that, as $\lambda \to \infty$,
>
> $\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot\Pr \{ X=\lfloor\lambda +x\sqrt\lambda\rfloor\}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp (-x^2 /2)+\mathcal{O}(\lambda^{-1/2})$
>
> (HINT: First argue
>   that the floor is not important, then apply Stirling’s formula)

I did it up to a certain point where I'm stuck now. Here is the last developement I found (by using Stirling from the Poisson mass function):

$\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot\Pr \{ X=\lfloor\lambda +x\sqrt\lambda\rfloor\}=\sqrt\lambda\frac{\lambda^{\lambda+x\sqrt\lambda}\exp(-\lambda)}{(\lambda+x\sqrt\lambda)!}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(x\sqrt{\lambda})\frac{1}{(\lambda ^2+x\lambda\sqrt{\lambda})^{\frac{1}{2}+\lambda+x\sqrt{\lambda}}}$

I tried to develop with Newton's Binomial then reuse Stirling but it's a mess.

Please I need help,
thank you

Comment: Maybe $(1 + \frac{a}{n})^n \rightarrow e^a$ helps.

Comment: Yes I tried it but I'm still stuck after (but at least I found an exp(-x²) and some lambda^(-1/2). Need to work more. Thanks anyway

Comment: Is it $\lambda +x \lambda$ or $\lambda +x \sqrt \lambda$?

Comment: It's the second one I'm correcting it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z=\lambda + x \sqrt{\lambda}$, with $x$ fixed and $\lambda \to \infty$

Then, assumming $z$ is an integer, $$P(X=z)= e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^z}{z!}=e^{-\lambda} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi z}} \left(\frac{\lambda e}{z}\right)^z (1+O(1/z)) \tag{1}$$

Now consider

$$\begin{array}{rcl} \displaystyle\log \left(\frac{\lambda e}{z}\right)^z &=&\displaystyle(\lambda +x\sqrt{\lambda})\left(1-\log\left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)\right)\\
&=&\displaystyle(\lambda +x\sqrt{\lambda})\left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}}+\frac{x^2}{2\lambda} + O(\lambda^{-3/2})\right) \\
&=&\displaystyle\lambda -\frac{x^2}{2} + O(1/\sqrt{\lambda}) \tag{2}
\end{array} 
$$

(Notice that a cancelation of terms occurs here - that's why you need to take the second order Taylor expansion of the logarithm)

Hence $$e^{-\lambda}  \left(\frac{\lambda e}{z}\right)^z = e^{-x^2/2+ O(1/\sqrt{\lambda}) } \tag{3}$$

Can you go on from here?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I don't understand why we have $o(\lambda^{-1})$ in particular (not depending on x). I'm not used to work with Landau notation, though

Comment: Remember that $x$ is here a constant. Hence the term $-x^3 /\sqrt{\lambda}$ tends to zero as  $1/\sqrt{\lambda}$ hence it (and the rest of the expansion) is $O(1/\sqrt{\lambda})$

Comment: Ok I understand well this part until the end now. I replaced then in $(1)$ but I'm not sure about the developement of $e^{O(1/\sqrt\lambda)}$ and how to work inside $O(1/(\lambda +x\sqrt\lambda))$. Is this last one equal to $O(1/\sqrt\lambda)$ ?

Comment: For the exponential, recall that for small $y$, $e^y \to 1 + y + \cdots$, hence $e^{O(1/\sqrt\lambda)}$ can be written as $(1 + O(1/\sqrt\lambda))$.

Comment: $O(1/(\lambda +x\sqrt\lambda))$ is the same as $O(1/\lambda )$ ($\lambda$ dominates over $x \sqrt{\lambda})$

Comment: Good thanks I arrived finally; it was a lack of knowledge finally! I think also that it is $x^2/2\lambda$ in $(2)$ (in the Taylor expansion of log).

Comment: YOu are right - fixed, together with an error in sign.